# Sqlite Bulk insertion Error on multiple tables in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, ios9

I have more than 200 tables and each tables have no.of records.These data are come from server before enter inside the app. I sync the data to local sqlite db. I am using following method for bulk insert of table and its data

```
+(BOOL)doUpdateQuery:(NSString *)query withParams:(NSArray *)params {
//static sqlite3 *masterDB;
 // static sqlite3_stmt *init_statement = nil;

    NSString* statement;

    statement = @"BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBase, [statement UTF8String], -1, &query_stment, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("db error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase));
        return NO;
    }
    if (sqlite3_step(query_stment) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        sqlite3_finalize(query_stment);
        printf("db error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase));
        return NO;
    }

    statement = query;
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBase, [statement UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
       // for(int i = 0; i < [params count]; i++){
        int i = 0;
        for(id param in params){
            i++;
           // NSString *param = [params objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([param isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
                sqlite3_bind_text(query_stment, i, [param UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            if ([param isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] ) {
                if (!strcmp([param objCType], @encode(float)))
                    sqlite3_bind_double(query_stment, i, [param doubleValue]);
                else if (!strcmp([param objCType], @encode(int)))
                    sqlite3_bind_int(query_stment, i, [param intValue]);
                else if (!strcmp([param objCType], @encode(long)))
                    sqlite3_bind_int(query_stment, i, [param longValue]);
                else if (!strcmp([param objCType], @encode(long long)))
                    sqlite3_bind_int64(query_stment, i, [param longLongValue]);
                else if (!strcmp([param objCType], @encode(BOOL)))
                    sqlite3_bind_int(query_stment, i, [param intValue]);
                else
                    NSLog(@"unknown NSNumber %@",[NSNumber class]);
            }
            if ([param isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
                sqlite3_bind_double(query_stment,i , [param timeIntervalSince1970]);
            }
            if ([param isKindOfClass:[NSData class]] ) {
                sqlite3_bind_blob(query_stment, i, [param bytes], [param length], SQLITE_STATIC);
            }
            while(YES){
                NSInteger result = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
                if(result == SQLITE_DONE){
                    break;
                }
                else if(result != SQLITE_BUSY){
                    printf("db error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase));
                    break;
                }
            }
            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);

        }

        // COMMIT
        statement = @"COMMIT TRANSACTION";
        sqlite3_stmt *commitStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBase, [statement UTF8String], -1, &commitStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            printf("db error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase));
            return NO;
        }
        if (sqlite3_step(commitStatement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
            printf("db error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(dataBase));
            return NO;
        }

        //     sqlite3_finalize(beginStatement);
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        sqlite3_finalize(commitStatement);
        return YES;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

and send the data for implemented in following method

```
+(BOOL) insertTable:(NSString *)TableName columnNames:(NSArray *)arrColumns data:(NSArray *) arrData {

[stringQuery setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ VALUES (",TableName]];

for (int i=1; i<=[arrColumns count]; i++) {
    [stringQuery appendFormat:@"?%d",i];
    if(i!=[arrColumns count])
        [stringQuery appendString:@","];
}

[stringQuery appendString:@")"];

NSLog(@"DBQuery******************************** %@",stringQuery);

if ([DBManager doUpdateQuery:stringQuery withParams:arrData]) {
    return YES;
}

return NO
}
```

but I am using this i can't insert data. I got a error like **cannot start a transaction within a transaction**. How to solve this issue what i am doing wrong

Comment: What part of the error message did you not understand?

Comment: @CL. I can't understand error  cannot start a transaction within a transaction

Comment: @CL. This method insert the column values one by one what i am doing wrong

Comment: Do you know what a transaction is? What the BEGIN and COMMIT statements do?

Comment: @CL. transaction means changes in the queries..begin means starting point of the transaction and COMMIT is endpoint of the transaction

Comment: And what does "transaction within a transaction" mean?